# Sql query optimalization

Tags: php, sql, pdo

My `ch_skills` table looks like

```
uid | skill1 | skill2 | skill3 | skill4 | skill5
1     1        2        2        0        1
2     1        1        2        1        1
3     1        2        3        0        1
```

My first question: is this correct? I mean would it be better if I made it like this:

```
uid | skillid | skill_lvl
1     1         1
1     2         2
1     3         2
1     4         0
1     5         1
```

Everything worked fine until now with the example #1, but now I'm in a trouble with the sql queries. Currently, I'm using 5 different queries to get the level of each skill. I use the following code:

For skill1:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `skills`.`skill_ID` as `Skill1_id`, 
   `skill_name`.`skill_name` as `Skill1_name`, `skill_level` as `Skill1_level`, 
   `skill_price` as `Skill1_price` 
   FROM `skills`, `skill_name`, `ch_skills` 
   WHERE `skill_name`.`skill_ID` = `skills`.`skill_ID` 
   AND `skills`.`skill_ID`= 1 
   AND `skills`.`skill_level` = `ch_skills`.`skill1`
   AND `ch_skills`.`uid` = :uid");
```

For skill2:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `skills`.`skill_ID` as `Skill1_id`, 
   `skill_name`.`skill_name` as `Skill1_name`, `skill_level` as `Skill1_level`, 
   `skill_price` as `Skill1_price` 
   FROM `skills`, `skill_name`, `ch_skills` 
   WHERE `skill_name`.`skill_ID` = `skills`.`skill_ID` 
   AND `skills`.`skill_ID`= 2 
   AND `skills`.`skill_level` = `ch_skills`.`skill2`
   AND `ch_skills`.`uid` = :uid");
```

And so on... As you can see, there's only two differences: skill_id = 2, and `skill2` as the coulmn's name. Is there any way for querying all the 5 skills in only 1 query? Or would you recommend me anyway to change the table structure?

Note: `skills` stands for the skill prices, and `skill_name` for the skill's names.

Comment: change the table structure

Comment: Unless you have very specific reasons not to, always normalize your tables.

Comment: Those tables have been created years ago, I don't know why I have done it the way like this. Thanks for the advices, I will change the structure.

Comment: First question, yes it would be better to change.  Second question,  once you normalize your data, then you can just use `WHERE SkillId Between 1 AND 5` and only have a single query.  Finally, look into using the standard `INNER JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I've been thinking... why is it better if I make it like the example #2? Number 1 means every user has 1 row, and there are no NULL values anywhere. "0" means skill is not trained yet, but it has to be there. Do you still recommend me to change the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other commenters have suggested, your best choice is to change the table exactly as you proposed.

The biggest reason not to have a wide table like you show in your first example, is that adding a skill means changing the structure of the database, which could break existing queries.

Secondly, as you see when you're trying to query the results, having a single table doesn't even make it easier to work with.

The only possible benefit to a non-normalized table like your example is that it takes up slightly less disk space.  But in todays world, disk space should never be your primary concern.

To answer your question about querying the original non-normalized example, however, there are two ways to do it:

1. Use a union statement which would combine 5 distinct queries together.  This is pretty inefficient
2. Create a table with (in this case) 5 rows (or if you have a Skills table use that).  Then join the ch_skills table to that, which should take each row and split it 5 times.  See below: (note: I'm assuming for the purposes of this example that skills and skill_name are in a 1:1 relationship and only have 5 records each)

   SELECT `skills`.`skill_ID`,
      `skill_name`.`skill_name`, 
      `skill_level` as `Skill_level`, 
      `skill_price` as `Skill_price` 
      FROM `skills`
     JOIN `skill_name` on `skill_name`.`skill_ID` = `skills`.`skill_ID`
     JOIN `ch_skills`
      WHERE `ch_skills`.`uid` = :uid
        AND ((`skills`.`skill_ID` = 1 AND `skills`.`skill_level` = `ch_skills`.`skill1`)
          OR (`skills`.`skill_ID` = 2 AND `skills`.`skill_level` = `ch_skills`.`skill2`)
          OR (`skills`.`skill_ID` = 3 AND `skills`.`skill_level` = `ch_skills`.`skill3`)
          OR (`skills`.`skill_ID` = 4 AND `skills`.`skill_level` = `ch_skills`.`skill4`)
          OR (`skills`.`skill_ID` = 5 AND `skills`.`skill_level` = `ch_skills`.`skill5`))

Comment: Sorry - for some reason the code formatting wasn't working on my answer